# Best way to fetch multiple objects from database, based on a list of objects of the same type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core

let's say I have a list of 10000 new Products (without IDs). Product has ID, SellerId, SKU and Color properties.

Now I need to check if those products already exist in my database, I can't use ID so instead of Unique Id I will use combination of SellerId and SKU. It's impossible that the product will have the same SKU for the same seller.

How can I do it in a most efficient way? Can this be done in LINQ? I currently loop through the list fetching each and updating individually, but I am sure there is a much better way.

Comment: you use EF? or other ORM?

Comment: @Sajid Yes, trying to do this in LINQ but can't figure it out.

Comment: Badly formed question, BTW.  Create existing list - `dbset.Where(item => item.property1 == x && item.property2 == y).Select(item => item.id)` Of course, speaking of "most efficient" way should add "using EF". Because EF often is not most efficient way by any means.

Comment: you can use ``join`` to get exiting data from data base [join](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/linq-to-entities/join-query-entity-framework/), and update or add your list in DB.

Comment: Is it an option to load all products from database to memory? If it is, then you could build a [lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2) with key `ValueTuple<int, string>` (assuming these are the types of SellerId and SKU), and then make very efficient searches using the lookup.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Or better: all `SellerId` and `SKU` values, not entire product records.

Answer (score -1):

```
Using Sytem.Linq;


var IList<Items> products = ...;
var existed_products = dbcontext.Products
                              .Where(
                                 x=> products.Any(
                                             y=> 
                                                 y.SellerId == x.SellerId && 
                                                 y.Sku == x.Sku &&
                                                 ))
                              .ToList()
```